# Google Play game services - hide / unhide achievements

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, achievements

I have Achievement `A` and Achievement `B`
To start off, I do not want to show `B` - I want it hidden.
BUT, when `A` is unlocked, I want to show `B`

Any way to do this with Google Play Game Services - Achievements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  So in the Play Console configure Achievement A to have the initial state of Revealed, and Achievement B to be Hidden.  When you want to reveal Achievement B, call [Games.Achievements.reveal(mGoogleApiClient, "ACH_B")](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements.html#reveal(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String))

You can read more about Achievements at https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements

Comment: NICE! Exactly what I was looking for. Will try it out later. Thank you.